# Pulling Tag-Specific Data from a XML Document with XPath

Tags: php, arrays, xpath, domdocument, domxpath

I am trying to extract `<description>` tag data from a XML document using DOMDocument and XPath, domXpath. I only want `<description>` data that is preceded by the tag `<header id="1236">MECHANICAL</header>`. So far I have created this as my xPath flow; however, it has been unsuccessful in calling the data:

```
($xpath->query('//VehicleDescription/standard[header="MECHANICAL"]/description')
```

I believe the issue lies in `VehicleDescription`. Any ideas on how to fix this? Bear in mind this is a Soap result, so the `VehicleDescription` and all the other data for the matter will change with every request.

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <S:Body>
  <VehicleDescription country="US" language="en" modelYear="2015" bestMakeName="Audi" bestModelName="A4" bestStyleName="4dr Sdn Auto quattro 2.0T Premium" bestTrimName="Premium" xmlns="urn:description7b.services.chrome.com">

 <standard>
    <header id="1236">MECHANICAL</header>
    <description>Engine: 2.0L DOHC 4-Cylinder TFSI -inc: Audi valvelift system</description>
    <category id="1048"/>
    <category id="1054"/>
    <category id="1213"/>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1236">MECHANICAL</header>
    <description>Transmission: 8-Speed Automatic w/Tiptronic -inc: sport program and manual shift mode</description>
    <category id="1130"/>
    <category id="1195"/>
    <category id="1220"/>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1236">MECHANICAL</header>
    <description>Full-Time All-Wheel Drive</description>
    <category id="1041"/>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1236">MECHANICAL</header>
    <description>Engine Oil Cooler</description>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1236">MECHANICAL</header>
    <description>80-Amp/Hr Maintenance-Free Battery w/Run Down Protection</description>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1236">MECHANICAL</header>
    <description>150 Amp Alternator</description>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1236">MECHANICAL</header>
    <description>Gas-Pressurized Shock Absorbers</description>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1236">MECHANICAL</header>
    <description>Front And Rear Anti-Roll Bars</description>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1236">MECHANICAL</header>
    <description>Electric Power-Assist Speed-Sensing Steering</description>
    <category id="1084"/>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1236">MECHANICAL</header>
    <description>16.1 Gal. Fuel Tank</description>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1236">MECHANICAL</header>
    <description>Single Stainless Steel Exhaust</description>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1236">MECHANICAL</header>
    <description>Multi-Link Front Suspension w/Coil Springs</description>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1236">MECHANICAL</header>
    <description>Multi-Link Rear Suspension w/Coil Springs</description>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1236">MECHANICAL</header>
    <description>4-Wheel Disc Brakes w/4-Wheel ABS, Front Vented Discs, Brake Assist, Hill Hold Control and Electric Parking Brake</description>
    <category id="1018"/>
    <category id="1020"/>
    <category id="1228"/>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1176">EXTERIOR</header>
    <description>Wheels: 8.0J x 17" 10-Spoke-Star-Design</description>
    <category id="1123"/>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1176">EXTERIOR</header>
    <description>Tires: P245/45R17 AS</description>
    <category id="1092"/>
    <category id="1097"/>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1176">EXTERIOR</header>
    <description>Wheels w/Silver Accents</description>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1176">EXTERIOR</header>
    <description>Steel Spare Wheel</description>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1176">EXTERIOR</header>
    <description>Compact Spare Tire Mounted Inside Under Cargo</description>
    <category id="1098"/>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1176">EXTERIOR</header>
    <description>Clearcoat Paint</description>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1176">EXTERIOR</header>
    <description>Express Open/Close Sliding And Tilting Glass 1st Row Sunroof w/Sunshade</description>
    <category id="1069"/>
    <category id="1132"/>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1176">EXTERIOR</header>
    <description>Body-Colored Front Bumper</description>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1176">EXTERIOR</header>
    <description>Body-Colored Rear Bumper</description>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1176">EXTERIOR</header>
    <description>Rocker Panel Extensions</description>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1176">EXTERIOR</header>
    <description>Aluminum Side Windows Trim and Black Front Windshield Trim</description>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1176">EXTERIOR</header>
    <description>Body-Colored Door Handles</description>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1176">EXTERIOR</header>
    <description>Body-Colored Power Heated Side Mirrors w/Manual Folding and Turn Signal Indicator</description>
    <category id="1064"/>
    <category id="1065"/>
    <category id="1174"/>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1176">EXTERIOR</header>
    <description>Fixed Rear Window w/Defroster</description>
    <category id="1034"/>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1176">EXTERIOR</header>
    <description>Light Tinted Glass</description>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1176">EXTERIOR</header>
    <description>Speed Sensitive Rain Detecting Variable Intermittent Wipers w/Heated Jets</description>
    <category id="1127"/>
    <category id="1159"/>
    <category id="1160"/>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1176">EXTERIOR</header>
    <description>Galvanized Steel/Aluminum Panels</description>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1176">EXTERIOR</header>
    <description>Black Grille w/Chrome Surround</description>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1176">EXTERIOR</header>
    <description>Trunk Rear Cargo Access</description>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1176">EXTERIOR</header>
    <description>Programmable Projector Beam High Intensity Low/High Beam Daytime Running Auto-Leveling Headlamps w/Washer and Delay-Off</description>
    <category id="1061"/>
    <category id="1168"/>
    <category id="1169"/>
    <category id="1313"/>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1176">EXTERIOR</header>
    <description>Front And Rear Fog Lamps</description>
    <category id="1151"/>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1176">EXTERIOR</header>
    <description>Cornering Lights</description>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1176">EXTERIOR</header>
    <description>Perimeter/Approach Lights</description>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1176">EXTERIOR</header>
    <description>LED Brakelights</description>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="10689">ENTERTAINMENT</header>
    <description>Radio: Audi Concert System w/1CD Player -inc: MP3 capable, AM/FM radio, auxiliary input jack, SD card slots w/32GB capacity for MP3 files, speed-dependent volume control, Audi MMI radio plus system for controlling infotainment/climate/car setup w/6.5" color screen, Audi music interface w/iPod integration w/1 cable for iPod connection, Audi 6-channel DSP extended 180 watt sound system w/10 speakers including subwoofer and SiriusXM satellite radio w/90-day trial subscription</description>
    <category id="1014"/>
    <category id="1017"/>
    <category id="1149"/>
    <category id="1150"/>
    <category id="1230"/>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="10689">ENTERTAINMENT</header>
    <description>Radio w/Clock and Steering Wheel Controls</description>
    <category id="1161"/>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="10689">ENTERTAINMENT</header>
    <description>Audio Theft Deterrent</description>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="10689">ENTERTAINMENT</header>
    <description>Window Grid Diversity Antenna</description>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="10689">ENTERTAINMENT</header>
    <description>Bluetooth Wireless Phone Connectivity</description>
    <category id="1211"/>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
    <description>Power Front Seats -inc: 8-way power front seats and 4-way power lumbar adjustment for driver</description>
    <category id="1074"/>
    <category id="1075"/>
    <category id="1082"/>
    <category id="1189"/>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
    <description>Driver Seat</description>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
    <description>Passenger Seat</description>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
    <description>60-40 Folding Bench Front Facing Fold Forward Seatback Rear Seat</description>
    <category id="1076"/>
    <category id="1304"/>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
    <description>Manual Tilt/Telescoping Steering Column</description>
    <category id="1087"/>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
    <description>Gauges -inc: Speedometer, Odometer, Engine Coolant Temp, Tachometer, Oil Level, Trip Odometer and Trip Computer</description>
    <category id="1203"/>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
    <description>Power Rear Windows</description>
    <category id="1126"/>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
    <description>Leather Steering Wheel</description>
    <category id="1192"/>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
    <description>Front Cupholder</description>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
    <description>Rear Cupholder</description>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
    <description>Front Cigar Lighter(s)</description>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
    <description>Ashtray</description>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
    <description>Valet Function</description>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
    <description>Power Fuel Flap Locking Type</description>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
    <description>Remote Keyless Entry w/Integrated Key Transmitter, 4 Door Curb/Courtesy, Illuminated Entry and Panic Button</description>
    <category id="1062"/>
    <category id="1063"/>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
    <description>Remote Releases -Inc: Power Cargo Access</description>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
    <description>HomeLink Garage Door Transmitter</description>
    <category id="1204"/>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
    <description>Cruise Control</description>
    <category id="1033"/>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
    <description>Dual Zone Front Automatic Air Conditioning</description>
    <category id="1009"/>
    <category id="1010"/>
    <category id="1011"/>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
    <description>Rear HVAC w/Separate Controls</description>
    <category id="1011"/>
    <category id="1012"/>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
    <description>HVAC -inc: Underseat Ducts and Console Ducts</description>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
    <description>Illuminated Locking Glove Box</description>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
    <description>Driver Foot Rest</description>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
    <description>Interior Trim -inc: Aluminum Instrument Panel Insert, Aluminum Door Panel Insert, Aluminum Console Insert and Aluminum/Metal-Look Interior Accents</description>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
    <description>Full Cloth Headliner</description>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
    <description>Leatherette Door Trim Insert</description>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
    <description>Leather Gear Shift Knob</description>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
    <description>Leather Seating Surfaces</description>
    <category id="1078"/>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
    <description>Day-Night Rearview Mirror</description>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
    <description>Driver And Passenger Visor Vanity Mirrors w/Driver And Passenger Illumination</description>
    <category id="1175"/>
    <category id="1176"/>
    <category id="1177"/>
    <category id="1178"/>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
    <description>Full Floor Console w/Storage, Mini Overhead Console w/Storage and 3 12V DC Power Outlets</description>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
    <description>Front And Rear Map Lights</description>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
    <description>Fade-To-Off Interior Lighting</description>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
    <description>Full Carpet Floor Covering -inc: Carpet Front And Rear Floor Mats</description>
    <category id="1055"/>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
    <description>Carpet Floor Trim and Carpet Trunk Lid/Rear Cargo Door Trim</description>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
    <description>Cargo Space Lights</description>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
    <description>FOB Controls -inc: Trunk/Hatch/Tailgate, Windows and Sunroof/Convertible Roof</description>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
    <description>Driver / Passenger And Rear Door Bins</description>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
    <description>Power 1st Row Windows w/Front And Rear 1-Touch Up/Down</description>
    <category id="1126"/>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
    <description>Delayed Accessory Power</description>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
    <description>Power Door Locks w/Autolock Feature</description>
    <category id="1063"/>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
    <description>Systems Monitor</description>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
    <description>Redundant Digital Speedometer</description>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
    <description>Trip Computer</description>
    <category id="1203"/>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
    <description>Outside Temp Gauge</description>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
    <description>Analog Display</description>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
    <description>Manual Anti-Whiplash Adjustable Front Head Restraints and Manual Adjustable Rear Head Restraints</description>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
    <description>Front Center Armrest and Rear Center Armrest w/Storage</description>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
    <description>2 Seatback Storage Pockets</description>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
    <description>Perimeter Alarm</description>
    <category id="1013"/>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
    <description>Immobilizer III Engine Immobilizer</description>
    <category id="1166"/>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
    <description>3 12V DC Power Outlets</description>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>
 <standard>
    <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
    <description>Air Filtration</description>
    <styleId>369101</styleId>
    <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
 </standard>

</VehicleDescription>
```

Here is my php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">

 <head>
 <title>Dynamically Generate Select Dropdowns 2</title>
 <style type="text/css">
   select {display: block;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;}
 </style>
 </head>

 <body>

   <?php

     $xml = file_get_contents('note.xml');
     $dom = new DOMDocument();
     $dom->loadXML($xml);
     $xpath = new domXpath($dom);

     foreach ($xpath->query('//VehicleDescription/standard[header="MECHANICAL"]/description') as $mechdescription) {
     $mecharray[] = $mechdescription->nodeValue ;
     }

     foreach ($mecharray as $mechanicaldescription){
     echo $mechanicaldescription ."\n\n";
     }
  ?>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the `<VehicleDescription>` node defines it's own default namespace (in `xmlns="urn:description7b.services.chrome.com"`), you will need to register this namespace and use it as part of your XPath expression...

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$xpath->registerNamespace("def", "urn:description7b.services.chrome.com");
$mecharray = [];
foreach ($xpath->query('//def:VehicleDescription/def:standard[def:header="MECHANICAL"]/def:description') as $mechdescription) {
    $mecharray[] = $mechdescription->nodeValue ;
}
```

I use `def` as the namespace prefix, but you can use whatever you want as long as it's the same in the XPath expression.

Comment: Thanks so much! Can you extrapolate more on the namespace logic? I still don't fully understand why that needs to be registered.

Comment: Do you mean what namespaces are or how they are used in XPath?

Comment: how they are used in XPath

Comment: In your original document you have a couple of namespaces, `xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"` and `xmlns="urn:description7b.services.chrome.com"`.  When you want to locate anything using XPath you need to ensure it's searching the correct namespace (in case the same element existed in more than one).  But to allow your XPath expression to use a prefix (`def` in this case), you have to tell it what that prefix equates to as the URI (`urn:description7b.services.chrome.com` in this case).

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you so much!